# Javascript image width and height undefined values

Tags: javascript

I try to get width and heigh from previewFrame and i set values to 100% both but when i try to alert it always get undefined values. Here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="frame.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="previewWrapper">
    <div id="previewFrame">
        <img id="previewImage" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg">                    </img>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="frame.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here is my css:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    background:#ccc;
}

#previewWrapper{
    margin:44px 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 88px);
}

#previewFrame{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:44px;
    background:#000;
}

#previewFrame img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;

}
```

and this is my js:

```
    function imageInfo() {
    var pFrame = document.getElementById("previewFrame");
    pFrame.setAttribute('style', "width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 88px);");
    var frameWidth = pFrame.width;
    var frameHeigh = pFrame.height;
    var pImage = document.getElementById("previewImage");
    var imageWidth = pImage.width;
    var imageHeigh = pImage.height;
    alert('Frame size is '+frameWidth+'px x '+frameHeigh+'px');
}
window.onload = imageInfo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `setAttribute` is a method, not an object with property `style`. So it should be

```
pFrame.setAttribute('style', "width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 88px);");
```

The second problem is that in order to read browser-calculated CSS properties you need to use `getComputedStyle` method:

```
var pFrameStyle = window.getComputedStyle(pFrame, null);
var frameWidth = pFrameStyle.width;
var frameHeigh = pFrameStyle.height;
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yxz4201q/2/